# input height different in ios

Tags: html, ios, css, height

I have a Search-Bar and a Button on the right, inside a div called homesearchcontent. The problem is that on IOS touch devices the Search-Bar is heigher than the Button.

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<form action='./results.php' method='post' class="homesearchcontent">
    <input type='text' name='input' id="searchdevice" class="search-field"  placeholder="" /> 
    <input type='image' src='img/search6.png' class="search-button">
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.homesearchcontent { 
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.search-field {
    -webkit-border-radius: 3;
    -moz-border-radius: 3;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: solid #191919 1px;
    padding-right: 1%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    width: 70%;
    height: 40px;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none; 
}
.search-button {
    outline: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    clear: both;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 2px 7px 2px 7px;
    border: solid #191919 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: The problem exist on all mobile devices or only on iOS ?

Comment: Only on IOS TOUCH devices. On Mac and other non-IOS touch devices it works.

Comment: You are not closing the second input, i think this is the problem  <input type='image' src='img/search6.png' class="search-button">
you need to close it />

Comment: Thank you for note this. Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `box-sizing: border-box;` and same heights for both inputs.

Comment: You sir are a god upon men :P